# Unable to locate package mysql admin and query browser (Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install Mysql server on Ubuntu. But it's not working as expected, show me the error

> "E:Unable to locate package mysql-admin"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open The Terminal
Follow These Steps

STEP-1. sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://www.tolaris.com/apt/ precise main'

STEP-2. wget -q http://www.tolaris.com/apt/tolaris-keyring.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -

STEP-3. sudo apt-get update

STEP-4. sudo apt-get install mysql-query-browser

Answer (score 1):

Both, MySQL Admin and MySQL Query Browser [had been discontinued](http://dev.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html) as of December 18, 2009.  Both of these tools had been replaced by MySQL Workbench, which you can [download from MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html) as a separate package.